# Convert JSON from URL to JSONNode

Tags: java, json

My code is now:

```
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.HashMap;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonNode;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.*;


public class WeatherClient {
    public static void main (String[] args) {
      try { final JsonNode node = new ObjectMapper().readTree(new URL("http://api.wunderground.com/api/5bef7a0ecc7f2933/" +
              "conditions/q/CA/San_Francisco.json"));
      }
          catch (Exception exception) {
          exception.printStackTrace();
      }
}


       }
```

and I get:

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonFactory.createParser(Ljava/net/URL;)Lcom/fasterxml/jackson/core/JsonParser;
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper.readTree(ObjectMapper.java:1792)
    at WeatherClient.main(WeatherClient.java:10)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:120)

Is there any way to solve this?

Comment: Hmmwait, what do you want? To obtain the JSON at that URI as a `Map`? Why not as a `JsonNode`?

Comment: @fge I wanted to do it as a Map so I could then categorise it, i.e. I don't need the whole thing.  Hope that makes sense.

Comment: Well, see my answer then. `JsonNode` is much more suited for JSON navigation than a `Map`.

Comment: @fge Yeah cheers for that, sorry I didn't see your answer before commenting, otherwise I wouldn't have done so.  Thanks again.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I see no reason why you'd need to use a `Map<String, Object>` when Jackson has the almighty `JsonNode`:

```
final JsonNode node = new ObjectMapper().readTree(new URL("yourURLHere");
```

See the [javadoc for `JsonNode`](http://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-databind/javadoc/2.2.0/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/JsonNode.html). You can navigate your JSON easily, in fact much more easily than with a `Map`. See methods `.get()`, `.path()`, etc etc.

(shameless plug) And if you want to use [JSON Pointer](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6901) to navigate your JSON, [you can also do that](https://github.com/fge/jackson-coreutils):

```
final JsonPointer ptr = JsonPointer.of("current_observation", "display_location");
final JsonNode displayLocation = ptr.get(node);
```

Comment: It wouldn't work with ObjectMapper, I get that this method can't be applied to a URL.  I changed it to:

Comment: It does work; if it doesn't, it means you use an old version of jackson-databind. Update to the latest (2.2.x) ;)

Comment: I've now altered the code.  I'm getting a NoSuchMethodException, and am struggling to know how to deal with it.

Comment: Please show the dependencies you have. You should go with jackson-core, jackson-databind and jackson-annotations, all 2.2.x

Comment: com.springsource.com.fasterxml.jackson.core.jackson-core-2.0.2.jar
jackson-annotations-2.0.2.jar
jackson-core-asl-1.7.0.jar
jackson-databind-2.2.1.jar
jackson-mapper-asl-1.0.0.jar

Comment: There you are, as you can see some them are older than that.  I will update them later, and hope that that solves the issue.